# Pasted folder replaced old one without asking in windows

Tags: windows, copy-paste

Was hard to describe my problem in Title. Basically I opened zip archive, and dragged a map out of it to desktop. Then I realized, that I had a map with the same name on desktop with different content and windows just replaced the old map with new one, without asking.
What I want to know is if there is any place I can find the old map, that got replaced? Can't really find it and the content was really important.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, because I myself have this situation for the first time and could not describe the problem to google.
So again, what I did:

1. Opened zip archive.
2. Dragged one folder on desktop
3. The folder replaced an existing folder on desktop, which apparently had the same name.

**SOLVED**

The solution was quite simple, but I will leave this post up, if anyone else gets this kind of problem, or by mistake clicked replace folder.
At least in windows 10, you can press properties of the new folder and there preview previous versions of the folder. Then click open and you can get the contents back. Or just click restore for restoring the folder to previous version.

Comment: This behavior sounds strange to me. Did you check your recycle bin?

Comment: @JulianHeinovski yes, the recycle bin was the first place I looked into :D anywho, I updated the question with solution.

Comment: You can write an answer on your own. Then the question gets marked as solved ;-)